# Can I get away with one user on Microsoft exchange?

Tags: exchange, office365

I have a small company with four emails that are all shared between myself and partner:

```
Myname@example.com
Hisname@example.com
Support@example.com
Info@example.com
```

We both read each others and have access to each others accounts. Do I need two user accounts on Microsoft’s plan? Or can I just setup one user and make the other three general inboxes?

Looking to switch off our IMAP accounts.

Comment: If you follow the TOS I believe you technically have two users.  If you ignore that you can probably make it with one user, would they ever catch you?  Who knows... but if they do it will be because of the number and type of devices all logging into one account.

Answer (score 2):

At the cost of Office 365 accounts you are doing yourself a great disservice trying to do all of this under one account. You are literally going to save $60/yr which is ridiculous. You’re going to have multiple issues such as problems sending mail as one email address or another. It will be impossible to use this on a mobile device. In addition there are many other components that build on top of that user account and you may inadvertently find yourself with conflicts that there is no easy way out of.

Do it right. The proper way to do this is to purchase two accounts, one for each partner. Then, setup two shared mailboxes for the other two addresses. Grant both accounts access to all the other accounts and shared mailboxes. Then each mailbox will show up individually in Outlook and each person will be able to send mail as any of the addresses. The from address will be naturally selected based on which mailbox is being currently viewed or which email is being replied to.

No matter what you do, if you intend to view and use any mailbox other than the primary mailbox on a native mobile app, you will have to enable logins for the shared mailboxes and add all accounts individually to your mobile device with separate usernames and passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn’t sure if there would be any issues at all since essentially the accounts are used like shared inboxes but this answers the question. I think the price would be a little higher as we will need the unlimited storage account but still point taken. Thanks!